# Tikz-cd and commutative diagrams

Tags: minipage, tikz-cd

Hello everyone :) Tikz is new for me so I'm asking you this question. I use Tikz-cd to write an arithmetic sequence. So far so good. I want to put this in a minipage and there's where the problem comes:

If I compile this out of a minipage:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
 x_{1} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{2} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & 
x_{3} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{4} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & 
x_{5} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r",end anchor={[yshift=0.225cm]north}] & 
\ldots
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

It gives no problems. But If I put this in an minipage environnement like

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\underline{\textbf{Définition}}:\newline\newline

Une suite \textbf{arithmétique} est 



$\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$\newline 

$\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$ \newline

$\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$ \newline

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
  x_{1} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{2} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{3} 
\arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{4} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{5} 
\arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r",end anchor={[yshift=0.225cm]north}] & \ldots
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}}\newline\newline
```

It gives the same 15 compilation erros "Undefined control sequence blablablabla l.... \end{minipage}\newline\newline". It's weird for me. Is there somebody that can explain the problem to me please :) ? Is there a possibility to put the diagram in the minipage like I would like to ? :) In advance Thx Everybody.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets, that makes it a lot easier to help you

Comment: The issue is with `\fbox`, not `minipage`. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution consists in using the `framed` environment, which has the advantage to break across pages.

However, while I'm at it, it would be simpler to define  an unnumbered theorem environment in the `break` style, since the  `ntheorem` package has a `[framed]` option.

In the code below I show both solutions. Finally, I advise against underlining theorem titles. Typographically speaking, this is very bad practice, which dates back to the ancient times of type writers, when it was not easy to change fonts and use  italic or boldface.

```
\documentclass[french, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, framed]{ntheorem}

\colorlet{framecolor}{Tomato}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoreminframepreskip{0ex}
\theoreminframepostskip{0ex}
\theoremprework{\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}\let\oldfbox\fbox\def\fbox#1{\color{framecolor}\oldfbox{\color{black}#1}}}
\newframedtheorem{defi}{Définition}

\begin{document}


\begin{framed}\parindent = 0em
  \underline{\textbf{Définition}}:

  Une suite \textbf{arithmétique} est

  $\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$

  $\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$

  $\dotfill$

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      x_{1} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{2} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{3}
      \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{4} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{5}
      \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r",end anchor={[yshift=0.225cm]north}] & \ldots
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{center}

\end{framed}%

\begin{defi}
  Une suite \textbf{arithmétique} est

  $\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$

  $\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots$

  $\dotfill$

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      x_{1} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{2} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{3}
      \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{4} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] & x_{5}
      \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r",end anchor={[yshift=0.225cm]north}] & \ldots
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{center}
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot everybody for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

For technical reasons, when a TikZ matrix (and a `tikzcd` is such an object) is absorbed as the argument to another command, the `ampersand replacement` option must be enforced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\textbf{Définition}

\bigskip

Une suite \textbf{arithmétique} est 
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  x_{1} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] \& x_{2} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] \& x_{3} 
\arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] \& x_{4} \arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r"] \& x_{5} 
\arrow[r,red,bend left,"+r",end anchor={[yshift=1ex]north}] \& \dots
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]