# How to use tikz in fbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am trying to put a diagram into a box as

```
\fbox{
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
}
```

The whole code is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[new]{old-arrows}
\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\fbox{ d}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

But it gives me error every single time. Is there any way to put the diagram into box?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408497/box-around-tikz-cd-diagram-without-ampersand-replacement https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395129/tikz-cd-and-commutative-diagrams

Comment: Also related: [Q601552](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/601552), [Q664078](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664078)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] \& B \\
\& C
\end{tikzcd}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that the category codes are fixed if the contents are grabbed as an argument once. The following uses the `grabbox` package, to define an alternative form of `\fbox` that doesn't grab its contents as an argument but as a `\hbox` (you could use the `collectbox` package, too).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[new]{old-arrows}
\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\usepackage{grabbox}

\newcommand\Fbox
  {%
    \begingroup\grabbox0\hbox{\fbox{\usebox0}\endgroup}%
  }
\begin{document}
\Fbox{\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}}
\end{document}
```

[image]