# tikz-cd conditional statement with diagrams

Tags: tikz-cd

Is there a standard way to make a tikz-cd figure consisting of two commutative diagrams appearing side by side with a \Rightarrow in between them? I would like to write a conditional statement with diagrams.

Comment: Welcome! Is this a typography question? Just place them both besides each other and place a `\Rightarrow` between them (in math mode, of course). Should both CDs have the same rows? Do they need braces around them?

Comment: As an example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664078/

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know figures were stacked horizontally, this is good to know. Then I just changed the baseline parameter suggested by egreg and it worked well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the diagrams side by side, the only problem is the vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-axis_height]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & D \arrow[dl] \\
E
\end{tikzcd}
\implies
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-axis_height]
X \arrow[r] \arrow[dr] & Y \arrow[d] \\
& Z
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: never knew about that baseline parameter, looks useful for numbered diagrams and such. Thanks!